Forecasting Square Waves
I am involved in a social experiment with other college students. The experiment involves simulating current price of the market at which a given asset can be bought or sold for immediate delivery. We, the participants negotiate on the current price; our professor would then record the negotiated value, we are allowed to call a meeting and negotiate at most three times per day. Our professor showed us the graph of the data, which looks like.

Our professor asked us to forecast the value of the price prior to our next "meeting". Obviously I can perform moving average on the data and perform ARIMA, but closer inspection of the graph looks like a digital signal, I am wondering if there are techniques that can be used to forecast digital signals. One approach is to use Fourier Transform, turn the square signal into a sinusoidal signal then perform  prediction, but I am wondering if this would be the right path.

What's a digital signal?

apologies I should have used the term square wave.

This looks like the price only changes at certain points in time, e.g., after some waiting time. I would start by trying to understand the waiting time distribution and the distribution of price change at each change point. This could be used in a simulation. (If the price follows a random walk, your MSE-optimal forecast is just the last observed price, no need to worry about the waiting time at all.)
